# jquery open selection open programmatically

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to open a select element by the following code but with no luck.

```js
$("#surveyno-select").trigger('mousedown');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="surveyno-select" class="form-control" onchange="loadquery(this)" selectionorder="4">
  <option value="-1">Please Select a Surveyno</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your question is lacking an incredibly lot of information and code. Define "open a select element" and elaborate on what 'exactly' you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Assuming you mean that you programmatically want to open the list of `option` elements in a `select`, then no, that's not possible.